# How to to store http-cookies between sessions

Tags: android, http, cookies

I'm developing an app that logs into a web site. To do this I use the HttpClient object.

I noticed I could get all the cookies from the post requests with the HttClient.getCookieStore method, the question is however how I save these cookies so the next time the app is started, the user don't have to log in.

I should also mention that while the login was post request, rest of the site is mostly get requests, does this effect how the cookies are managed at all?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082799/android-how-to-store-cookies/4083144#4083144