# Android non synchronizing Cookies

Tags: android, cookies, synchronization

I'm developing apps on iOS and Android where I have a web of shopping and when I buy an item, the web gives me a value on the cookie that I get and then I show the number of items that the client has purchased.

The way to take the cookies is:

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
String cookies = cookieManager.getCookie(url);
```

so, when I have 20 products and I add one, it turns to 21 (obviously) but when I remove one item, it stays on the same number because the cookies don't get updated.

I'm using the same login with Objective C and it updates well.

Am I missing anything on Android?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use cookies to store information about economical transactions? really? What happens if you reset your browser cache or your phone? What if you return to the store using another device?

Comment: I lose it all in that case

Comment: Of course. You should be using a server hosted database.

Comment: I know, but I don't work alone and that's not my deal. The project was projected like this, and I have to face this problem.

Comment: Uh-oh. You should change your project manager, then.

Comment: Thanks for your annotation @FrankN.Stein, I wish I could do something.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082799/android-how-to-store-cookies